# How do I get the sum of radio button values in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have the following codes for my radio buttons and this is for my full menu programming project with tkinter:

```
     from tkinter import *
     from time import sleep


class SchoolCampMenuGUI:
    def __init__(self,parent):
#------------------------------Layout Of Menu------------------------------------------#
        Top=Frame(parent,bg="white")
        Top.pack(side=TOP) #frame for title School Camp Menu
        lblTitle=Label(Top,font=('New York Times',15),text="\t\tSchool Camp Menu\t\t\n(Please choose 1 breakfast,lunch and dinner and below 8700KJ) ")
        lblTitle.pack() #setting fonts and size
        f4=Label(borderwidth=3,relief=SUNKEN)
        f4.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
        f1=Label(borderwidth=3,relief=SUNKEN,bg="white")
        f1.pack(side=LEFT) #first label for Breakfast
        f2=Label(borderwidth=3,relief=SUNKEN,bg="white")
        f2.pack(side=RIGHT) #second label for Lunch
        f3=Label(borderwidth=3,relief=SUNKEN,bg="white")
        f3.pack() #third label for dinner
        def onclick1():
            r.set(None)
            q.set(None)
            v.set(None)
        def clear():
            sleep(0.5)
            f4.configure(text="")#define the definition of RESET button all value set to None to reselect choices and clears all calculations.

       
                 
        b1=Button(f4,text="RESET",width=8,bg="red",command=lambda:[onclick1(),clear()])#calling the combined function
        b1.pack(side=RIGHT)
    
        def total():
            total=int(v.get())+int(r.get())+int(q.get())
            f4.configure(text="Your Current Total Is: "+total+" KJs.")
            
            

        r=StringVar()
        v=StringVar()
        q=StringVar()
        r.set(0)
        v.set(0)
        q.set(0)
        
            
              
#--------------------------------------Lunch--------------------------------------#
        lblMeal=Label(f3,text="Lunch",font=('arial',14,'bold'),bg="white")
        lblMeal.pack()

        rb1=Radiobutton(f3,text="Chicken Burgers",variable=r,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=1180,bg="white",command=total)                                
        rb1.pack(anchor=W)

        rb2=Radiobutton(f3,text="Chicken Curry and Rice",variable=r,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=1800,bg="white",command=total)
        rb2.pack(anchor=W)

        rb3=Radiobutton(f3,text="Teriyaki Chicken Sushi *Gluten Free",variable=r,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=1730,fg="violet",command=total)
        rb3.pack(anchor=W)

        rb4=Radiobutton(f3,text="Caprese Panini *Gluten Free",variable=r,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=2449,fg="violet",command=total)
        rb4.pack(anchor=W)

        rb5=Radiobutton(f3,text="Vegetable Risotto *Vegetarian",variable=r,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=1432,fg="blue",command=total)
        rb5.pack(anchor=W)

        rb6=Radiobutton(f3,text="Gourmet Vegetable Pizza *Vegetarian",variable=r,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=1463,fg="blue",command=total)
        rb6.pack(anchor=W)
    

#----------------------------------Breakfast----------------------------------#

        Meal=Label(f1,text="Breakfast",font=('arial',14,'bold'),bg="white")
        Meal.pack()

        rb7=Radiobutton(f1,text="Bacon and Egg Muffin",variable=v,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=1240,bg="white",command=total)                                
        rb7.pack(anchor=W)

        rb8=Radiobutton(f1,text="Scrambled Eggs & Bake Beans",variable=v,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=1533,bg="white",command=total)
        rb8.pack(anchor=W)

        rb9=Radiobutton(f1,text="2 Weet-Bix w/ milk",variable=v,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=1110,bg="white",command=total)
        rb9.pack(anchor=W)

        rb10=Radiobutton(f1,text="Pancakes w/ syrup",variable=v,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=2019,bg="white",command=total)
        rb10.pack(anchor=W)

        rb11=Radiobutton(f1,text="Bread with jam",variable=v,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=491,bg="white",command=total)
        rb11.pack(anchor=W)

        rb12=Radiobutton(f1,text="Cinnamon Roll Doughnuts",variable=v,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=1130,bg="white",command=total)
        rb12.pack(anchor=W)       

#----------------------------------dinner-----------------------------------#

        Dinner=Label(f2,text="Dinner",font=('arial',14,'bold'),bg="white")
        Dinner.pack()

        rb13=Radiobutton(f2,text="Spaghetti Bolongnese",variable=q,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=1523,bg="white",command=total)
        rb13.pack(anchor=W)

        rb14=Radiobutton(f2,text="Beef Burgers w/ Chips and Salad",variable=q,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=3620,bg="white",command=total)
        rb14.pack(anchor=W)

        rb15=Radiobutton(f2,text="Meatball and Butter Bean Stew *Gluten Free",variable=q,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=1820,fg="violet",command=total)
        rb15.pack(anchor=W)

        rb16=Radiobutton(f2,text="Roast Beef *Gluten Free",variable=q,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=2280,fg="violet",command=total)
        rb16.pack(anchor=W)

        rb17=Radiobutton(f2,text="Creamy Broccoli Gnocchi *Vegetarian",variable=q,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=2800,fg="blue",command=total)
        rb17.pack(anchor=W)

        rb18=Radiobutton(f2,text="Vegetable Wellington *Vegetarian",variable=q,font=('arial',12,'bold'),value=2270,fg="blue",command=total)
        rb18.pack(anchor=W)
```

Is there a way to add all values together but not getting them? This is for my school menu project. Any help appreciated.
Note: The values are in KJs for food. So far I have all the values but they are just put there, e.g. 11801800, but not adding it up. I used r.get()+v.get() but they don't actually add the values up.

Comment: So I have changed to IntVar() and 
            def total():
                 total=int(v.get())+int(r.get())+int(q.get())
                 f4.configure(text="Your Current Total Is: "+str(v.get())+"+"+str(r.get())+"+"+str(q.get())+"="+str(total)+" KJs.") and it is now working.

Comment: The calls to `str()` are unnecessary. `v.get()` already returns a string :)

Comment: okie, thanks! idk why but it didn't work for me at first until I added str().... tkinter doesn't like me lmao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do add up. Your problem is that r.get() returns a string, not an integer. First convert them, then sum up.

```
int(r.get()) + int(v.get())
```

Comment: Hi, so I tried your method but this is the error that I am getting:  can only concatenate str (not "int") to str. Is there a work around? Thanks. I have this for my total thanks to your help: 
def total():
            total=int(v.get())+int(r.get())+int(q.get())
            f4.configure(text="Your Current Total Is: "+total+" KJs.")

Comment: @Cheezdoodle Did you convert all `.get` results to ints?

Comment: Thanks, it is now working, I have put in the comment above.